# Pivot Query using With Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using MySQL to try to manipulate some data for cancer research and machine learning. It seems an ideal problem for the PIVOT statement but I can't quite get it to work and would welcome any help. If there's a better tool, like maybe R, I'm all ears too.

Let's say I have three tables, patients, samples, and mutations:

- patients table has unique rows, each with a unique patient_id.
- samples table has unique rows, each with a unique sample_id, but also a patient_id that can be found in the patients table. There may be multiple rows in the samples table with the same patient_id.
- mutations table has NON-unique rows. Each row in the mutations table contains just two columns: gene and sample_id.

I need to create a new table, call it summary, with patient_id in the first column, sample_id, followed by a column for every distinct gene in the mutations table.

Each row of the new summary table should contain

- the patient_id from the patients table,
- the sample_id from the samples table,
- a the number 1 in each following gene column for each gene in the mutations table that has a sample_id for the specific patient or a number 0 if not.

New summary table looks sort of like this:

```
    patient_id  sample_id  gene A  gene B  gene C  gene D  etc
    12345678    54321      1       0       0       0
    23456789    65432      0       1       1       0
    34567890    76543      0       0       1       0
    34567890    87654      0       1       0       1
    etc
```

The new summary table must have an entry, either a 0 or a 1, for every distinct gene found in the mutations table even if there are no entries in the mutations table that have a sample_id belonging to the patient for a specific row.

Remember, there may be multiple samples belonging to the same patient, so the summary table could contain multiple rows for a given patient - each row for a different sample.

Here's my current non-working SQL:

```
SELECT cs.patient_id, g.*
FROM samples cs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (WITH cp AS
        (SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT gene FROM mutations GROUP BY gene) c
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT sample_id FROM samples GROUP BY sample_id) m)
    SELECT cp.gene, cp.sample_id, IFNULL(m.id,0) id
    FROM cp 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT gene, sample_id, 1 id FROM mutations) m on m.gene=cp.gene and m.sample_id=cp.sample_id)     
    PIVOT ( MAX(id) for gene in ('BAP1','PDGFRA','KRAS','CDKN1B','IDH1','ARID1A','DOT1L','NOTCH4','ABL1',
                                'PBRM1','MLL3','TET2','SPEN','CCND2','DDR2','RICTOR','SMAD4','GLI1','RASA1',
                                'MAP2K1','CSF3R','HIST1H3D','DNMT3B','CEBPA','GATA2','ARID1B','BRCA2','EPHA7',
                                'CTNNB1','EPHA5','EP300','RAF1','NF1','EGFR','NBN','INHA','CARD11','ANKRD11',
                                'ERBB3','TERT','DNMT1','ATM','RIT1','PDCD1','SMARCA4','FOXP1','DICER1','TGFBR2',
                                'PTPRS','FANCC','APC','NCOA3','NTRK1','PTPRD','NSD1','GRIN2A','SMARCB1','PTCH1',
                                'KEAP1','KDR','IRS2','PIK3R3','SUFU','STAG2','MAP3K13','SOX9','SETD2','FAT1',
                                'ZFHX3','NRAS','MAP3K1','ERBB4','JAK3','NF2','PGR','KDM6A','RPTOR','TP53','CIC',
                                'MSH2','MAP2K4','AXIN2','PTEN','XPO1','ERCC4','AXL','RNF43','DNMT3A','ERG','NOTCH2',
                                'RFWD2','IGF1R','GATA1','SMAD3','TMPRSS2','MLL','BRAF','TET1','BCOR','YAP1','HLA-A',
                                'PLCG2','CBL','IRS1','PIK3CA','POLE','LATS2','MST1','H3F3B','IRF4','AR','B2M','NCOR1',
                                'FUBP1','NOTCH3','ATR','RPS6KB2','TSC2','PIK3CG','MDM2','ROS1','TCF3','TSC1','FGFR2',
                                'FBXW7','FOXA1','MEN1','CDKN2Ap16INK4A','EPHA3','PMS1','PAK1','E2F3','PIK3CD','PLK2',
                                'MPL','RHEB','RBM10','ASXL2','MSH6','RAD21','BRIP1','PTPRT','GNA11','CDKN1A','RAD50',
                                'BRD4','STK11','ARID2','RUNX1','MTOR','JAK1','TBX3','MALT1','RYBP','MLL2','PIK3CB',
                                'SMO','AXIN1','MAPK3','VHL','JUN','KDM5A','ARID5B','AMER1','PPM1D','ASXL1','MLH1',
                                'CASP8','BARD1','DAXX','CDH1','PALB2','AKT3','RECQL4','IGF2','MED12','FLT3','HIST3H3',
                                'MST1R','EIF4A2','CREBBP','STAT5B','PHOX2B','BRCA1','ERBB2','MITF','RB1','CD79A',
                                'TMEM127','MAPK1','CDKN2A','CDKN2Ap14ARF','CSF1R','FLT4','CENPA','RPS6KA4','SRC',
                                'ERCC3','NEGR1','RET','ACVR1','SYK','ICOSLG','FYN','SOX17','ETV6','NTRK3','HIST1H1C',
                                'IDH2','CHEK1','GNAS','PPP6C','EZH2','MYCL1','SDHA','MDC1','ARAF','RAC1','KDM5C','PARP1',
                                'NKX2-1','CXCR4','SMAD2','IL7R','TGFBR1','U2AF1','SF3B1','FGFR4','ERRFI1','SMARCD1','FGFR1',
                                'EPHB1','PDPK1','FLCN','RAD54L','MGA','PPP2R1A'))
    ) g on g.sample_id = cs.sample_id;
```

Sample data text files

- patients - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NhRkHvvydmZ5ilHJ4TwKE_AslNFvCOcS
- samples - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Txdaa7JKOVMS3TZ8g9tkQUzZPkNc2m24
- mutations - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-HXEszbpcrkPX7MomJnkcAsVCKuzl-rJ

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Those are 2 different products with different syntax.

Comment: `;with cp as (sel...) select * from cp join sample...` try like this

Comment: SQL Server in this case

Comment: Although the test data seems anonymized to certain degree or even generated, you should only include those columns that are actually required for the query.

Comment: yes, it is de-identified data from the public domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be over complicating this query when it should be a lot simpler. Here's an example on how to get the first 3 columns, you would just need to copy paste and replace for the rest.

```
SELECT s.patient_id,
        s.sample_id,
        MAX( CASE WHEN m.gene = 'BAP1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BAP1,
        MAX( CASE WHEN m.gene = 'PDGFRA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PDGFRA,
        MAX( CASE WHEN m.gene = 'KRAS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS KRAS
FROM samples s
LEFT JOIN mutations m ON s.sample_id = m.sample_id
GROUP BY s.patient_id,
        s.sample_id;
```

If you want to create this query dynamically, you can do it to prevent writing a large amount of code.

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Columns = ( SELECT CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) + ',MAX( CASE WHEN m.gene = ' + QUOTENAME( gene, '''') + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(gene)
                FROM mutations
                GROUP BY gene
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')

SET @SQL = N'SELECT s.patient_id ' + NCHAR(10)
         + N'    ,s.sample_id '
         + @Columns + NCHAR(10)
         + N'FROM samples s ' + NCHAR(10)
         + N'LEFT JOIN mutations m ON s.sample_id = m.sample_id ' + NCHAR(10)
         + N'GROUP BY s.patient_id, ' + NCHAR(10)
         + N'        s.sample_id;' + NCHAR(10)

PRINT sp_executesql --For debugging purposes
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL --, @ParametersDefinition, @Param1, @Param2, ..., @ParamN
```

Comment: I do like this solution - ideally, the code would be smart enough to generate the list of genes (ie. BAP1, PDGFRA, etc) dynamically based on what's in the data so there would be no editing of the code required...